# user mark a location on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add an ability to the user to mark their stores location on google map and then I get the user's marked coordinates and store it .How can I do so.

This is my current code which just display a location :

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = {lat: 35.6961, lng: 51.4231};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

  map.addListener('click', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would comment this but i cant, this is quite simple, you already have a working code for marking points in Gmaps, just give the the user methods to save some coordinates, you can even grab the coordinates with gmaps when you click the map. but the easy way is to let the user input their own data. then store the data in a database and then you could tweak a bit this code for your needs:

```
var mapProp = {
     //this is the starting point of the map
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.847811, -70.483842),
     zoom: 8,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);



                       for (var mark in json) {
                            var lat = json[mark].estaciones_latitud;
                            var long = json[mark].estaciones_longitud;
                            var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                title: json[mark].estaciones_nombre
                            });
                            marcador.setMap(map);//sets the point in map
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click',function () {
                                doSomething(this.internalPosition.A, this.internalPosition.F, this.title);//this listener works when you click the mark
                            });
                        }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

this is a working code thats grabs every point i pass on this json object and drwas on the map the points.